# Excel VBA, a for loop for changing a variable and pasting its result

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

I have a spreadsheet with a series of calculations. I have a result cell which is dependent on all calculations. I have written a macro that:

1. asks user for range between two numbers
2. generate range with 0.5 spacing between two numbers
3. for each number, add this number to specified cell and wait for processing
4. copy result cell to summary cell
5. repeat for all numbers in range

number 4 in this routine is my only issue. I can't seem to get the result from each loop to paste in a different cell. For example, for a range between 1 and 3, I should have 5 values. I want these values to be pasted next to their pressure value.

```
  Sub pressureOptimization()
'
' pressureOptimization Macro
'

    p1 = InputBox("Give lower pressure limit")
    p2 = InputBox("Give higher pressure limit")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For StartNumber = p1 To p2 Step 0.5

        Range("D21").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = StartNumber
        Range("C34").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Result").Select
        Range("C2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Main Simulation").Select

        Next StartNumber
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is fairly straightforward in python but a little more complicated in VBA. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your code, I don't know why you are pasting in Results!C2 if you want it next to your pressure value. Here is code that would put it next to your StartNumber variable cells which I'm assuming are on the Main Simulation sheet.

```
Sub pressureOptimization()
'
' pressureOptimization Macro
'
Dim x As Integer
p1 = InputBox("Give lower pressure limit")
p2 = InputBox("Give higher pressure limit")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

x = 0

For StartNumber = p1 To p2 Step 0.5

    Sheets("Main Simulation").Cells(21 + x,4).Value = StartNumber
    Sheets("Main Simulation").Cells(21 + x,5).Value = Sheets("Result").Range("C34").Value

    x = x + 1

Next StartNumber

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If Results!C34 is only updating from 'Main Simulation'!D21, then I would suggest doing whatever results calculation Results!C34 is doing directly in your code. However, without more details of whats in the cells and how the sheet works it's hard to give you an exact answer on how to make it work.

Comment: Although this didn't fully answer my question, it did put me on the right path. I just had to flip around the sheet selections and copy and paste rather then use '='. Thanks for your answers :)